# Constraint violation in GLPK (Pulp wrapper)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, glpk, pulp

I'm using Pulp with GLPK solver and have follow constraint:

```
-1000000*f1 + v1 + 1000000*f2 - v2 >= -10.999
```

Solver:

```
problem.solve(GLPK(options=['--mipgap', '0.000001', '--cuts']))
```

But in result I get solved problem (status 'Optimal') with constraint violation:

```
f1 = 0
v1 = 11
f2 = 1
v2 = 1000000
```

So, what can I do in this case? Can I increase accuracy somehow or use another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you run in problems with numerical accuracy. Your coefficients are in order of 1.e7 (and you want a solution with 1.e-6).  The solution needs to be at least correct in 1.e11 to hold the constraint and by argument you require maximum 1.e-14 relative error.

Simply that is much too much for a pure numercal solver. (Expect Maximum 1.e-6 to 1.e-7 to run reliable to an LP-Solver)There are exact solvers like QSopt and I also think, soplex got those features now.

Here is the link to QSopt
http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/downloads/downloads.htm

Here is the link to this soplex stuff.
http://soplex.zib.de/doc/html/EXACT.php

QSopt is available as binary only (I think) and SoPlex is free for research (as I understand).

Further u can use SCIP together with SoPLex. The have or had some exact IP Project. So, if license is ok for you, I would go with SCIP in this case.

Maybe, u could give a bit more insight your application, so that one can reformulate ur restrictions.

Comment: I see now ur full comment. Please follow up the answer, that I send u about your abs Question. VUB is usually not the best way to model abs-Values. With SOS-Constraints you can negotiate this numerical hazards, if you need the abs function. The best solver for your case (commercial and free) would be COIN-CBC. (see at www.coin-or.org).

Comment: btw, u can use cbc inside pulp

Comment: SOS-Constraints work extremely slow (compare with approach with +M), is it right or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: So, I just can tell you about SCIP, CPLEX and Gurobi, which tracks usually also numeric stability rather well. The problem with bigM's is, that it blows up the condition of your problem, leading to a lot more full factorizations of the LU-factorization in the simplex method instead of LU-updates, which slows down your iterations. Secondly, SOS-constraints imply several variable propagation rules, so that it usually performs better, than if you have a lot of vub constraints.

Comment: The point is, if your problem dies because of numeric problems, you have simply no other choice. In prinicple, it is hard to say in advance, what performs better.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And do you know any MIP solvers with numeric stability and free for commercial use? (As I understand SCIP, CPLEX and Gurobi not fully free).

Comment: Yes, but I have it, so I use it. I cannot tell you exact about coin-cbc, because I did not use it for a very long time. But as I know, Coin-OR is rather well maintained from several well known people from the OR-Community like John Forrest, Bob Fourer, etc.

  * Solving MIP's perform usually much better with COIN-CBC then with Glpk. See http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/milpf.html for example (unfortunately rather old, but glpk seems not to change so quickly). I would expect, that the implementation of SOS-Constraints in CBC is also well, because it is not so hard and the idea of SOS exists long time

Comment: But I cannot tell you from my own experience.
  * Here you can find a performace comparison with SCIP/CPLEX/Cbc http://scip.zib.de/
  * Commerical usage: GLPK is GPL and not LGPL and so also very restricted in usage. You even cannot use it more or less in combination with any other commercial software. COIN-CBC is CPL-Licensed and so much more compatible for commercial usage.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've also got that SOS conditions makes everything slow in case when I use very big bounds (like 10000000) for example.